# How to implement a swipemenu using Android RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I recently confront a problem in Android Development. That's how to achieve a swipemenu using Android RecyclerView? Also , I want to keey touch event when touch on items in RecyclerView.
[The effect may  like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtJOD.gif)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/custom-swipe-recyclerview.html

Comment: https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView

Comment: https://github.com/TUBB/SwipeMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below library which I have used in my project as well

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: You can use swipeLayout in your itemLayout

Comment: Well, after tough try, it finally works. But I still have a problem, what if I want to add Click event on items in the recyclerview with androidswipelayout? I mean, when I swipe, OnClick() method is also invoked, and that's not I want.